# How do I return a new array of array of dictionaries after sorting by dictionary value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I would like to return a new array made of arrays from an array of dictionaries that are to be sorted. I might not be explaining properly but I will just give examples of what I am trying todo.

So I have the following:

```
let foo = [{"id": "hello123"}, {"id":"goodbye123"}, {"id":"hello123"}];
```

I would like to sort it by the id value and return an array of array dictionary like so:

```
let bar = sortByKey(foo, "id");
console.log(bar);

output = [[{"id":"hello123"},{"id":"hello123"}],[{"id":"goodbye123"}]]
```

So far all I know how todo is sort it so that the outcome looks like:

```
[{"id":"hello123"},{"id":"hello123"},{"id":"goodbye123"}]
```

Comment: Where is your `sortByKey` function? What is the code that you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: what qualifies the sort order?

Comment: That's not sorting, that's partitioning.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the `sortByKey` function hasn't been made yet. currently using this `foo.sort((a,b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0));` from another post to sort it by id's value.

Comment: @Bergi I did not know the correct term for this method. Sorting made sense to me. Should I change the topic question?

Comment: You may just want to take unique values, sort them and partition them: https://jsfiddle.net/zp9eh2dc/1/ . Otherwise you can use `Array.reduce` to make it more efficient

Comment: @briosheje This is exactly what I wanted todo. Can you post it as an answer so I can upvote and choose it as the answer.

Comment: I think there are more efficient ways to do that. Using Reduce would be the best scenario here, check @NinaScholz 's answer below, it's significantly more performant than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the groups and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for iterating the array and assigns all object to their groups.

Later return all values from the hash table.

```js
function groupBy(array, group) {
    return Object.values(array.reduce((hash, o) => {
        hash[o[group]] = hash[o[group]] || [];
        hash[o[group]].push(o);
        return hash;
    }, Object.create(null)));
}

var data =  [{ id: "hello123" }, { id: "goodbye123" }, { id: "hello123" }];
 
console.log(groupBy(data, "id"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and slightly shorter.

```js
function groupBy(array, group) {
    return Array.from(array
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[group], [...(m.get(o[group]) || []), o]), new Map)
        .values()
    );
}

var data =  [{ id: "hello123" }, { id: "goodbye123" }, { id: "hello123" }];
 
console.log(groupBy(data, "id"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you. this does exactly what I need and works with big data too. I will go study it properly now so now I know what is happening instead of blindly using it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of providing another solution (despite @NinaScholz's solution is way better), here is a solution relying on `Set`, `map` and `filter`:

```js
let foo = [{"id": "hello123"}, {"id":"goodbye123"}, {"id":"hello123"}];

function sortByKey(arr, key) {
 const _uniqueValues = [...new Set(foo.map(i => i[key]))].sort((a,b) => (a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : ((b[key] > a[key]) ? -1 : 0));
  return _uniqueValues.map(v => arr.filter(i => i[key] === v));
}

console.log(sortByKey(foo, 'id'));
```

This will take unique values (using `Set`) first and sort them, then it will map them by partitioning the original array using `filter`.
The `reduce` solution will be more efficient, but it's still a possible way to do this.

**Please accept / read @NinaScholz's solution below, this is just an alternative to the solution provided. Using reduce is the correct approach**

Comment: Still like yours for the fact that I can understand whats going on slightly better but for the sake of efficiency I will give the answer to nina scholz instead. But thank you for the quick solution :)

Comment: @MarcoFernandes I think Nina won't mind explaining you what's going on in her solution, though ;)